# How to tell if adverb clauses are essential or not?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

"Essential clauses provide essential information and are not set off with commas."

"Non-essential clauses provide additional, non-essential information and need commas."

It seems so straightforward, isn't it, but not for me.

Speaking of adverb clauses, adverb phrases, etc, I don't know how to tell if they are essential or not. For me, I always think they have to be essential because they add information to the sentences.

Therefore, I found this site (https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9NAz60BVJKd8.html)

According to the site, the clause in bold in **Example 1** is a non-essential element. However, it does tell us information that is important. Without it, the listener might not know what action he had done at 8:30. So, how is that non-essential?

**Example 1**

> The package came at 8:30, **after you had left**.

I found another source (https://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/independent_clause.htm).

According to it, the clause in bold in **Example 2** is non-essential. So, how is that non-essential? Because "as you'd expect a young officer to" does provide information that would not be known if not said.

**Example 2**

> He died, **as you'd expect a young officer to**.

Comment: Of course the additional information is important (otherwise it wouldn't be mentioned at all), but it isn't essential to the meaning of the sentence. The listener must know that they left _before_ 8.30. The essential information is that that was when the package arrived, the speaker goes on to remind the listener that they had already gone by then.

Comment: By the way, you might find [this explanation](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/usage-of-essential-and-nonessential-clauses) more helpful

Comment: You can't define 'essential' that way, since the comma is not a foolproof test. "Essential' is not grammatical term here. In, for example,"The plane leaves (at 10.45)" the bracketed bit will typically be a vital part of the information being conveyed, but it is still an adjunct, an optional element.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is not whether the clause *provides information*, but whether it *changes* the information in the rest of the sentence.

---

Your first examples:

> The package came at 8:30, after you had left.

The fact that the listener had already left doesn't change the time the package arrived - this sentence would be *equally true*:

> The package came at 8:30

This particular example can also be switched around:

> The package came after you had left, at 8:30.

Which can be reduced to:

> The package came after you had left.

There are two facts which are *independent* of each other.

---

Your second example:

> He died, as you'd expect a young officer to.

The person is dead; the second clause doesn't change that, and removing it leaves a true sentence:

> He died.

The information about expecting young officers to die is *additional* information; it doesn't *modify* the meaning of the primary clause.

---

Now compare an essential clause:

> Everyone died who was a young officer.

If we remove the clause now, we *change the meaning* and many more people are dead:

> Everyone died.

The clause in this case is not just providing *extra* information, it is providing *essential* information about which people died.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. The "change information" part you said still puzzles me. For example, let's see these two sentences "I came home when my family were not at home" and "I came home, when my family were not at home." How does the when-clause change the information of the main clause?